# Communicate with MySQL Database with PHP in a jQuery Mobile Application

Tags: php, mysql, database, mobile, dreamweaver

I'm looking for the simplest system for communicating with a MySQL database and an app being developed for iOS.

All the data is on the online database and I'm looking for the user to be able to retrieve and submit information to the tables just as a normal desktop browser would.

I'm developing with Dreamweaver and packaging it for mobile release using the jQuery Mobile templates (which are in HTML), is there a way to do this?

Comment: So you only make a mobile optimized website? Then go with the standard PHP database api's [PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Not mobile optimised website - from Dreamweaver CS5.5 you can package your mobile as an iOS, Android or RIM application.

Comment: Else if you mean a native (hybrid) app with phonegap you need a web service on your server. This could be [Soap](http://php.net/manual/de/class.soapserver.php) or [Rest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

Comment: Rest with json response is the standard today. But there is no standard solution with PHP. You can use ready frameworks like [Recess](http://www.recessframework.org/) or [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.rest.server.html). You also need some kind of authorization for the web service. The best option would be to use [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)

Comment: But wait...if it's phonegap then it's a hybrid app which means that the content is hosted at your server and the display works through a native browser element on iphone. With this option you don't need a web service. But if the content is embedded into the app then you need a web service to communicate with the server.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help RedReggae - looks like I've got a lot of reading up to do, going from amateur PHP to learning about web services with json and authorisation is quite a leap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is the way forward! I created a web-service and used Javascript and jQuery to retrieve the values from the MySQL database.